# Modify values in a DataFrame index based on another index value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas and working with indices, especially MultiIndex. I have a DataFrame as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,1,2],
    'Measurement': ['ScanA', 'ScanA', 'ScanB', 'ScanB'],
    'Result':[0.1,0.2,0.5,0.7],
    'ResultType':['A','B','C','B']})
piv = df.pivot(index = 'ID', columns = 'Measurement', values = ['Result', 'ResultType'])
```

This creates two indices `Result` and `Type`, but I'd like to modify the values in the `Result` index based on the `Type` value.

For example, if `Type == 'C'` then I want the corresponding `Result` to be `-1`.

Another example would be if `Type in ('A', 'B')` then I want to set `Result` to be `0 if < 0.5 else 1`

How can I programatically do this without looping through each row/column?

Output for `piv.Result` would look like:

```
Measurement     ScanA   ScanB
ID      
1               0.0     -1
2               0.0     1
```

Comment: What is your expected output dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first modify the dataframe and then pivot

```
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'C', 'Result'] = -1
df.loc[(df['Type'].isin(['A', 'B'])) & (df['Result'] < 0.5), 'Result'] = 0
df.loc[(df['Type'].isin(['A', 'B'])) & (df['Result'] >= 0.5), 'Result'] = 1

df.pivot(index = 'ID', columns = 'Measurement', values = ['Result', 'Type'])

            Result          Type
Measurement ScanA   ScanB   ScanA   ScanB
ID              
1           0       1       A       A
2           0       -1      B       C
```

Edit: An alternative using np.select as @Wen-Ben suggested

```
cond = [df['Type'] == 'C', (df['Type'].isin(['A', 'B'])) & (df['Result'] < 0.5), (df['Type'].isin(['A', 'B'])) & (df['Result'] >= 0.5)]
choice = [-1, 0, 1]
df['Result'] = np.select(cond, choice)

df.pivot(index = 'ID', columns = 'Measurement', values = ['Result', 'Type'])
```

Comment: May check with np.select

Comment: I like the use `np.select` since these conditions may need to be adjusted with tuning over time.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to what Vaishali suggested, you can use `numpy.where` to modify `piv` after it is generated.

```
t = piv['Type']  
r = piv['Result'].astype(float)

piv.loc[:, 'Result'] = np.where(
    t == 'A', np.where(r < 0.5, 0, 1), np.where(t == 'C', -1, r))
piv

            Result        Type      
Measurement  ScanA ScanB ScanA ScanB
ID                                  
1              0.0   1.0     A     A
2              0.2  -1.0     B     C
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in the `pandas` library called `loc()` which allows the user to find the values of the row through calling its label. This function, along with the conditional selection offered by pandas, allows the user to find the row where certain conditions are true (similar to the `WHERE` functionality found in SQL) and set values for other columns in that row. Using these methods, I have added a portion to your code that sets the `'Result'` column to `-1` when `'Type' == 'A'`. You can apply the same structure to alter other `'Result'` rows based on `'Type'` values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,1,2],
    'Measurement': ['ScanA', 'ScanA', 'ScanB', 'ScanB'],
    'Result':[0.1,0.2,0.5,0.7],
    'Type':['A','B','A','C']})
piv = df.pivot(index = 'ID', columns = 'Measurement', values = ['Result', 'Type'])
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'C', ['Result']] = -1
print(df)
```